# Appsetting.json saying not found trying to use a Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: c#, json, dependency-injection, blazor-webassembly

I am working on a prototype app. Where we are using the new Blazor WebAssembly. What I am trying to do is access my JSON file to get access to endpoints we have setup to make API calls. This is what I have currently

appsettings.json:

```
    "Endpoints": {
    "AuthEndpoint": "https://auth"
  }
```

Program.cs:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .Build();
    //var endpointSettings = new EndpointSettings()
    //{
    //    AuthEndpoint = config["Endpoints:AuthEndpoint"]
    //};
    
    var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
    builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");

    builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) })
         .AddScoped<IAuthenticationService, AuthenticationService>()
         .AddTransient(_ =>
         {
             return config.GetSection("Endpoints")
                          .Get<EndpointSettings>();
         })
         .AddTransient<IAuthClient, AuthClient>();
    


    await builder.Build().RunAsync();
}
```

When it builds in the console log I am getting this error message
[image: ErrorMessage]

I am trying to find out why this happening and what can I do to fix it

Answer (score 0):

something along these lines for example:

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args)
                .Build()
                .Run();
        }

        
        public static IWebAssemblyHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            BlazorWebAssemblyHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                .UseBlazorStartup<Startup>();
        
    }

public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton(GetConfiguration());
        }
        public void Configure(IComponentsApplicationBuilder app )
        {
            app.AddComponent<App>("app");
        }

        public APISetting GetConfiguration()
        {
            // Get the configuration from embedded dll.
            using (var stream = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("appsettings.json"))
            using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
            {
                return System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<APISetting>(reader.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
    }
```

where APISetting class "matches" your appsettings.json:

```
public class APISetting
{
    public string AuthEndpoint { get; set; }
    ...
    ...
}
```

and appsettings.json "build action" is set as "Embedded resource"

Comment: It is set to embedded resource I will try this